# Can someone recommend a React component or NPM library that allows one to set up a WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: text-editor, cms, node.js, react, wysiwyg

We're working on a large project where we want to be able to have our clients publish articles.  We were originally considering Ghost (ghost.org) for this part of the project, but it's a bit limited in the ability to customize.  Then we looked at Keystone and Strapi, which seem very powerful, but lack the rich WYSIWYG editor that Ghost has.  I'm wondering whether there are any pre-built components (we are using React) or NPM libraries (and Node) that would allow us to mount an 'editor panel' for the clients' use.  It would allow us to create something similar to the Ghost editor (see pic).

- WYSIWYG editing (formatting, etc)
- easy to insert images and have them reflected WYSIWYG style in the document being edited
- easy to insert social media links (YouTube, Instagram, Spotify, etc) and have them reflected WYSIWYG style in the document being edited

Thanks for any leads!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think you should look into, editor libraries like tinyMCE, which is basic general purpose and customisable.
If you want something more powerful and customisable look into Gutenberg js.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Quill](https://quilljs.com/) to be very reliable and flexible.